# %d for naming input and output files in Python

Tags: python, for-in-loop

I want to automatically input some files that have names as in array "dates" and then save them after some operations but the code is not working:

```
dates=[20120711,20120712,20120713,20120714,20120715]
DEM="C:\\Path\\iranDem.tif"

for i in dates:
    Norma="C:\\Temporar\\%d.tif" 
    JoNorma="C:\\%d.tif"

    Delta=arcpy.sa.Times(DEM,0.0065)
    JoNorma=arcpy.sa.Minus(Norma,Delta)
    % i
```

Comment: How is this related with D tag?

Comment: It has to do with "%d" tag but the tag text box does not accept the "%" character.

Comment: NPE, I am working on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `%` operator in the *correct* locations:

```
JoNorma=arcpy.sa.Minus(Norma % i, Delta)
```

You cannot just put the `% i` on a separate line, the operator requires a string to operate *on*.

I corrected the indentation of your post, but I suspect that you don't realize that in Python, indentation is crucial. You need to make sure that all the lines that are part of the loop, are indented properly as is now displayed in your question.

Comment: I get the same error "Parsing error <type 'exceptions.IndentationError'>: expected an indented block (line 4)"
even after I did what you said: `dates=[20120711,20120712,20120713,20120714,20120715]
DEM="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\DEM\\iranDem.tif"

for i in dates:
Norma="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\LST Images\\2012 Products\\Temporar\\%d.tif" % i
JoNorma="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\LST Images\\2012 Products\\LST NotNormalized\\%d.tif"


Delta=arcpy.sa.Times(DEM,0.0065)
JoNorma=arcpy.sa.Minus(Norma % i,Delta)`

Comment: @ArditS.: You could have other errors in your code still, indentation errors have nothing to do with string interpolation. Run `python -tt yourscript.py` to detect where your indentation errors are.

Comment: @ArditS.: Did you indent the code block below the `for` loop? I suspect you need to read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before you continue.

Comment: `dates=[20120711,20120712,20120713,20120714,20120715]
for i in dates:
 DEM="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\DEM\\iranDem.tif"
 Norma="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\LST Images\\2012 Products\\Temporar\\%d.tif" % i
 JoNorma="C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\MSTH\\IRAN\\LST Images\\2012 Products\\LST NotNormalized\\%d.tif"


 Delta=arcpy.sa.Times(DEM,0.0065)
 zbritje=arcpy.sa.Minus(Norma, Delta) 
 zbritje.save(JoNorma % i)`

It worked this way.

Comment: @ArditS.: There is *no* point in posting code in a comment, especially when it's python.

Comment: Yes, I see. What should one do then if he/she wants to add some code after posting?

Comment: @ArditS.: You can edit your question if you need to add more information.